# How to design a system using only one account login to all application

Tags: oop, database-design, architecture, erp

I'm using Enterprise Resource Planning (ERP) and we have to design three desktop applications (a Finance management application, a human resource management application and a warehouse management application using object oriented programming).

The client wants each person in their company to have only one account for the three applications (like google account that let you access google drive, google mail, google+)

How can I design an account system in order to access each application?

Comment: I don't get it.. why don't you make all apps connect to the same database O.o

Comment: of courses we can use same database for all apps, but how about the permission of an account, how can we manage it?

Comment: You will have to search for some [Single Sign On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) implementations.

Comment: permission.. I don't understand you very clearly.. you mean permission to use the app or options within the app?

Comment: @JonesJoseph for example i have an account and i can access all features in warehouse management application but in human resource management application i don't have permission to create, delete or modify any record in that

Comment: @JustinVan its pretty simple.. maintain a table which has columns [userID],[menuID],[menuAllowed] which has menuAllowed='T' or 'F' based in every menu in your app.. this can make the task very tough, but trust me I have done it, and it works pretty great! I have about 18000 records in the rights table for an ERP I made. Just that it gives you ability to define the rights of the user on a 'menu' and 'button' level.

Comment: @JonesJoseph so the menuID is a group of buttons or textboxs, isn't it?

Comment: @JustinVan the [menuID] field is just the name..it holds the ID of buttons,menus,options etc... which also includes the edit, insert, delete buttons

Comment: @JonesJoseph ok, i got it. But did you have any ER diagram for this, I think i have to see some examples about that to get the best idea to make it

Comment: @JustinVan actually I don't have one.. because I don't have habit of reading anything before working on anything XD

Comment: @JonesJoseph ok, many thanks for your help. My habit is reading or finding how people do this and i can analyze the weakness so i can improve it or choose the best way and customize it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to create and account system to manage your unique ids.

  - An unique id can be an e-mail address, phone number, taxpayer identification number, an UUID (an auto-generated universal unique identification), a social id (gmail, github, facebook) or any other method to create it.
  - You can also set one primary and contactable unique id with alternative account ids.

---

- Now, consider the following responsibilities (a responsibility can be implemented by one or more classes):

  - An Activity (a command, action or method) to be managed.
  - An User that uses the account system and decorates a Person or any other Actor.
  - And an AccessRole responsible to keep who (an actor) can perform an activity.

Comment: So did you mean in database i have to maintain activity, user and accesrole of the user ?

Comment: You can map it it in that way but it won't be flexible, e.g., you need to inspect every call to an activity (a method of a class); thus, you decide to implement a Protection Proxy pattern. The decisions are in the realm of the object thinking, not data structures.  An activity is the abstract concept for concrete artifacts, e.g., methods and processes. When you get into data modelling, you have to consider restrictions and performance, so you can create an activities_table with a field to classify the kind of activities or create one table for each type of activity.